# AWS S3 Is it possible to delete the bucket file even if it is not a full file name?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-java-sdk

I am trying to delete a file from an AWS s3 bucket.
The full name of the file is "test11.mp4".

Can I delete files with only "test11" value without the extension?

For example, on Linux

```sh
rm -rf test11 *
```

I want to make it work this way...

Additional edits
I am using the AWS SDK for Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Java SDK, you can use `deleteObjects()` to delete multiple objects.

See: [Deleting Multiple Objects Using the AWS SDK for Java - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/DeletingMultipleObjectsUsingJava.html)

However, it is not possible to specify a wildcard. The specific `Key` of each object to be deleted must be provided.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `--include` and `--exclude` parameters to do this, but it only works with the `--recursive` option, so it might not be exactly what you want.

See:

- [rm — AWS CLI Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/rm.html)
- [Use of Exclude and Include Filters — AWS CLI Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html#use-of-exclude-and-include-filters)

Comment: I had a lack of explanation. I am using the AWS SDK for Java. I am deleting a file with the deleteobject function with s3 client.
like this,


amazonS3.deleteObject(this.getBucketName(), imgName);